# Searching a '.txt' file for a name and displaying the corresponding date

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on a program where the user enters their name and birthday. It then saves to a .txt file in the following format

- John Doe 4/10/2000  <---- (The name and the date is separated by a "tab", not a "space")

Everything is working in the program, I can display the data just fine as far as sorting the dates by month or by name, etc. But I don't know how to get the search function working properly. I have a textbox where the user will enter a name to search for. So if they enter John Doe, the program should then search that text file (birthday.txt) and display the date 4/10/2000. If that name is not found, the program should display a message stating the name was not found. Please help!

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far so people can help you fixing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Dim people = From line In File.ReadLines(path)
       Let userprops = line.Split({vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.None)
       Let Name = userprops.First()
       Let BirthDate = userprops.Last()
       Where Name.IndexOf(txtUsername.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1

If Not people.Any() Then
    MessageBox.Show("No user found with that name")
Else
    Dim firstUserBirthDate = people.First().BirthDate 
    MessageBox.Show(firstUserBirthDate.ToString())
End If
```

I have used `IndexOf` instead of `=` to show you how to search case-insensitively and part of the name.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that tonight and see how I make out. This line Dim people = From line In File.ReadLines(path), do I have to edit anything there? I'm guessing I remove "path" and put C:/birthday.txt or wherever the file is located? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: @Cliff: You have to use .NET 3.5 at least since that's a Linq query. If you use 3.5 you cannot use `File.ReadLines`, then you have to use `File.ReadAllLines`. Yes, replace path with the actual path. I haven't tested it, maybe you need to add `ToList()` to the query(parenthesize the query first, then add `ToList`) which materializes the query since `File.ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` which might be disposed after the first `people.Any`.